# What is a partial hit in code coverage?

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

Recently, when switching from Coveralls to Codecov coverage in my project dropped by a few percent. This seems to be due to *partial hits*, which are counted as hits in Coveralls but as misses in Codecov.

Here is a code example:

```
class Struct(object):                  # hit
    def __init__(self, content=None):  # hit            
        if content is not None:        # partial hit
            self.content = content     # missed

s = Struct()                           # hit
```

As far I see, the if statement is fully evaluated by the interpreter. Why is it not counted as a hit, then?

Comment: Presumably because you haven't tried both cases the `if` covers, which is also why the line inside the block is missed entirely.

Comment: Note that this is covered in the documentation: http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/branch.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, I had not realized this had to do with branch coverage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that on that line there is a branching statement but one of the branches was never executed.

From the following line, it is obvious that the content was not ever given to that constructor, so you never tested the code with `Struct(content=something)`.

Note also that if you do not give an argument, `self.content` will not be set, and thus `AttributeError` will be raised if access is attempted.

---

While *in this case you could deduce it from the statement inside `if`*, were the truth value opposite, you couldn't see that the condition was never *false*. Consider your example again, slightly modified

```
class Struct(object):                  # hit
    def __init__(self, content=None):  # hit            
        if content is not None:        # partial hit
            self.content = content     # hit

    def print_content(self):           # hit
        print(self.content)            # hit

s = Struct('42')                       # hit
s.print_content()                      # hit
```

Looks like everything is fine? If you **didn't use branch coverage, the `if` would also say *"hit"***, and you wouldn't notice that you never tested the code in the case that `content is not None` *is `False`*, which then would have the bug of not setting the `self.content` attribute: the following program:

```
s = Struct()
s.print_content()
```

when run, raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 10, in <module>
    s.print_content()
  File "foo.py", line 7, in print_content
    print(self.content)
AttributeError: 'Struct' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. If I understood correctly, the partial hit informs about potentially missed test cases. In this particular case such a test could uncover the bug of not setting `self.content`. Right?

Comment: @kazemakase hopefully I explained it better now

Comment: you explained it well enough from the start, but you've edited in some valuable information.