# how to avoid partial hit in codecov for a ternary assignment

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, conditional-operator, codecov

I have a vue function that returns an array of strings

```
1 selectStyles (): string[] {
2  const baseStyles = ['selected-label', 'px-4']
3  const placeholderStyle = this.internalValue?.length === 0 ? 'text-gray-400' : 'text-black'
4
5  return [...baseStyles, placeholderStyle]
6 },
```

And I have three jest tests cases testing for

1. if `internalValue` has a value and it's therefore its length is !0
2. if `internalValue` is an empty array and therefore its length is 0
3. if `internalValue` is undefined, `undefined === 0` is false and therefore second condition is assigned

And yet codecov says that line 3 is a partial hit?

Any idea why?

I read this [great response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36006975/6837445) concerning an if statement in python and the results of that, but I don't think it answers my question.

Here are my test cases:

```
  it('selectStyles', () => {
    expect(
      Select.computed.selectStyles.call({
        internalValue: []
      })
    ).toEqual(['selected-label', 'px-4', 'text-gray-400'])

    expect(
      Select.computed.selectStyles.call({
        internalValue: ['some opt selected']
      })
    ).toEqual(['selected-label', 'px-4', 'text-black'])

    expect(
      Select.computed.selectStyles.call({
        internalValue: undefined, // unlikely
      })
    ).toEqual(['selected-label', 'px-4', 'text-black'])
  })
```

Tyia!

Comment: Jest's code coverage is supported by [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/jest/), which has an [open issue, where optional chaining does not count as branch coverage](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/issues/516). But FWIW, I actually cannot reproduce the problem: the report generates full code coverage with that test code. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem where your reports show partial coverage?

Comment: unfortunately it's not a public repo but here is a screenshot of the relevant portion that's yellow i legend , same code as above https://github.com/saylestyler/tylsyl/blob/master/codecovpartial.png?raw=true @tony19

Comment: That screenshot doesn't offer anything more than what you've already described. Can you create a GitHub repo with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to check if `internalValue` is `undefined` or not as this operator returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined.

```
// Here if this.internalValue is undefined we are assigning it with an empty array.
this.internalValue = this.internalValue ?? []
```

Your logic will be like this **:**

```
selectStyles (): string[] {
  const baseStyles = ['selected-label', 'px-4']
  this.internalValue = this.internalValue ?? []
  const placeholderStyle = this.internalValue?.length === 0 ? 'text-gray-400' : 'text-black'
  return [...baseStyles, placeholderStyle]
}
```

I just gave my thought as per your problem statement. You can do modifications as per the actual code you have.